# Symfony2 LiipImagineBundle not work on Nginx

Tags: symfony, twig, liipimaginebundle

I am just trying to get working LiipImagineBundle.

```
#app/config/confiy.yml
# liip_imagine Configuration
liip_imagine:
resolvers:
    default:
        web_path:
            web_root: %kernel.root_dir%/../web
            cache_prefix: media/cache

loaders:
    default:
        filesystem:
            data_root: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/

#....
#...
filter_sets:
    medium:
        quality:              100
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [280, 280], mode: outbound }
#....
#...
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
            upload_folder: "uploads/"
```

if using:

```
app/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve /uploads/photos/3/01.jpg  --filters=medium
```

it work fine.

But after using:

```
#src/Hy/PhotoBundle/Resources/views/Photo/index.html.twig
  {% for entity in pagination %}
        {% set photo=upload_folder~entity.fileManaged.uri %}
         <img src="{{ asset(photo | imagine_filter('medium')) }}" />
   {% endfor %}
```

image is not rendered, path is simply not found error.

Any tips?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVbwv.png

Answer (score 1):

The default nginx configuration will short-circuit urls ending with jpg, gif etc to the file system and not to the application. You should to improve your nginx configuration like that:

```
location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ \.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$ {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        expires 365d;
        access_log off;
    }
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}
```